# VB.NET; Output sometimes doesn't appear on richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim A, B, Tambah, Kurang, Kali, Bagi, Hasil, HasilUji, x, y As Double

    Private Sub Variabel()
        A = tbAngka1.Text : B = tbAngka2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Kalkulasi()
        'Perhitungan Sederhana
        Tambah = A + B : Kurang = A - B : Kali = A * B : Bagi = A / B
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUji_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUji.Click
        rcHasil.Clear()

        Variabel()
        Kalkulasi()

'THE PROBLEM START HERE (WHILE)
'PLEASE HELP ME
'THIS SPAGGETTI CODE RUINING MY DAY :)

        'While
        'Segitiga
        If rbWhile.Checked Then
            Do While x <= Hasil '--> x = 1 : Hasil = 5
                y = 1
                Do While y <= x
                    rcHasil.Text += y.ToString
                    y += 1
                Loop
                rcHasil.Text += vbCrLf '--> vbCrLf : Utk ubah tampilan output Vertikal ke Horizontal
                x += 1
            Loop

            'Segitiga Terbalik
        ElseIf rbWhileTerbalik.Checked Then
            Do While x <= Hasil
                y = 1
                Do While y <= Hasil - x
                    rcHasil.Text += y.ToString
                    y += 1
                Loop
                rcHasil.Text += vbCrLf
                x += 1
            Loop

            'Play Button
        ElseIf rbWhilePlayButton.Checked Then
            Do While x <= Hasil
                y = 1
                Do While y <= x
                    rcHasil.Text += y.ToString
                    y += 1
                Loop
                rcHasil.Text += vbCrLf
                x += 1
            Loop

            Do While x >= 1
                y = 1
                Do While y < x - 1
                    rcHasil.Text += y.ToString
                    y += 1
                Loop
                rcHasil.Text += vbCrLf
                x -= 1
            Loop
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The output from While sometimes doesn't appear.

Need Help Fixing My Spaghetti Code :)

Comment: You should provide more information. What output do you expect and in which richtextbox?

Comment: That code is just all over the place. It needs to be more manageable. What ever problem you're trying to solve here, I'd strongly recommend you break it down into smaller pieces. Each of those Do...While loops should be in their own functions. It would make it easier to identify problems than it would be from that unorganized mass of code.

Comment: May I know if there are updates about the question?

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize x and y each time you click button as they are changed in loops. simply add

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

before

```
    If rbWhile.Checked Then
         Do While x <= Hasil '--> x = 1 : Hasil = 5
    [etc...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide does not initialize the values of x,y and Hasil, so they are both 0.

It is recommended that you initialize their values before the IF statement.

```
x = 1
Hasil = 5
If rbWhile.Checked Then
```